# Store are Not updating when dispatching an action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Here is my code: Dispatching the API response

```
CreateData(url, payload, function (response) {
      if (response.data !== "") {
        if (response.data !== null) {
          // setDisplayValidateData(response.data.AuditResultList);
          Promise.resolve(
            dispatch(
              setData({
               Data: response.data.AuditResultList,
              })
            )
          );
          console.log(response.data.AuditResultList);
          if (response.data.AuditResultList.length > 0) {
            waiting.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/Validate";
          }
          
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

dataSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "fs",
  initialState: {
    Data: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    setData: (state, action) => {
      state.Data.push(action.payload.Data); 
        console.log(action.payload.Data); //contains the Api response


    },
  },
});
export const { setData } = dataSlice.actions;

export default dataSlice.reducer;
```

Here the Store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";

import dataReducer from "./features/data/dataSlice";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 
  fs: dataReducer,
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

But when I try to retrieve the state from store! it is not updating

component.js

```
 const Data = useSelector((state) => state.fs.Data); //returns empty array

  console.log(Data); // []
```

store are not updating with response Data! i want to save the Api response in redux store so I can use it in different component! any suggestion is appreciated thankyou!

Basically what I'm doing is making API call, after getting a response successfully,I'm storing the API response in redux store, then I'm redirecting to the new screen in a new window, I want to retrieve that response on new screen (on new tab)! but I'm only getting the initial state!

Comment: Does the code reach `Promise.resolve...`?

Comment: yes Bro , i'm also getting the response in dataslice.js  while console.logging!!

Comment: Is `dispatch` declared using `const dispatch = useDispatch()`?

Comment: of course Bro, its declared using const dispatch = useDispatch()

Comment: You can't do what you want using just redux - opening a new window/tab will cause your application to restart from initial state. (as would reloading).

To achieve the behaviour you want, of opening a new tab while maintaining the updated state you would have to use cookies or localstorage.

Here is one example library that helps do that: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-sync-a-redux-store-across-browser-tabs/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
setData: (state, action) => {
    state.Data = [...state.Data, action.payload.Data]
}
```

Comment: I've tried it bro, but still, I'm getting an empty array!

Comment: In `redux-toolkit` mutation is allowed at reducers. So this shouldnt be the problem